# problems rounding. I want to round the value with 2 digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my loop in the house view show template:

```
- @region.cities.each do |city|
     %li
      = link_to city.name, country_region_city_path(@country, @region, city)
     %li 
      = @house.location.distance_from([city.latitude,city.longitude])
```

It shows the distance from the house to the cities.(geocoder gem). It works but i want to round the value with 2 after the point, like this by example 22.12 KM.

How can i implement the round method?

Caio..remco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `number_with_precision` helper.

```
<%= number_with_precision(@house.location.distance_from([city.latitude,city.longitude]), :precision => 2) %>
```

Docs at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision

Answer (score 0):

You can use round(x) where x is the number of decimals like:

```
@house.location.distance_from([city.latitude,city.longitude]).round(2)
```